# Why background-color: '#ff0000'; is an "invalid property value"?

Tags: css, background-color

I don't understand why background-color: '#ff0000'; is an "invalid property value".

**HTML**

```
<div id="aside">
  <div id="buttons-panel" class="control-panel">
      ...
  </div>
  <div id="client-panel" class="control-panel">
      ...      
  </div>
</div>
```

**strong text**
**CSS**

```
#aside {

  background-color: '#ff0000';
  width: 25%;
  height: 75%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  right: 20px;
  z-index: 10;
}
```

**Google tools**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dVlIB.png)

Everything looks fine except the background-color, I can't see whats wrong.
Thanks

Comment: Don't use quotes, just `background-color: #ff0000;`

Answer (score 6):

The hex value doesn't need to be a string:

```
#aside {
  background-color: #ff0000;
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use the hex colour without quotes, such as: `background-color: #ff0000;`.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried removing the quotes, the background-color value is not a string:

```
#aside {
  background-color: #ff0000;
  width: 25%;
  height: 75%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  right: 20px;
  z-index: 10;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why did you use quote in hex code.. Just remove it `#ff0000` like this

Answer (score 1):

It should be without '

```
#aside {
  background-color: #ff0000;
  width: 25%;
  height: 75%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  right: 20px;
  z-index: 10;
}
```